# Understanding bijection between polynomials and N

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I tried to find a bijection between N and polynomials
I was reading and thinking about   [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231050/831100):

> Given any polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, write $f(x) = a_1 + a_2 x + a_3 x^2 + \cdots + a_{n+1} x^n$.
>
> Let $p(n)$ denote the $n$th prime.
>
> Then we can map $f(x)$ to $\prod_{k = 1}^{n+1} {p_k}^{a_k} \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> You can also see how the reverse mapping would work.
>
> For example, the natural number $63 = 3^2 \cdot 7^1$ would map to the polynomial $g(x) = 2x + x^3$.
>
> So you could find a mapping from each natural number to a polynomial, then compute that polynomial's roots, then list them. Then repeat the process for the next natural number, tossing out any repeats of roots. This will give you a list of all the algebraic numbers.

This function is neat and amazing **but where " $0 "$ from naturals maps to?**

Is this statement contained in that function or we must Improve that?
Because prime numbers start from 2...

Comment: notice that 1 is the product of $p_k^0$, so it goes to the zero polynomial

Comment: @Exodd Oh thanks your right! But what about $0$?

Comment: Half of the world doesn't consider $0$ a natural number. By the way, that answer is also wrong in the sense that $a_k$ must be nonnegative for it to work...

Comment: First map the naturals without zero to the polynomials and then compose that map with the one that maps the naturals with zero to the naturals without zero.

Comment: Thank you all !